Scroll Instagram Followers Box Selenium Python
Tried all existing answers and seem to be out dated.
I'm trying to scroll down on the list. The driver finds the dialog box but for some reason it doesn't scroll, I've tried multiple scripts and none worked, what am I missing?
The script doesn't throw any erros but the scroll doesn't move.
FOLLOWERS_POPUP_XPATH = "//div[@role='dialog']" #"//div[@class='isgrP']" # '//div[@role="dialog"]//ul'

script = "arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight"

followers_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, FOLLOWERS_POPUP_XPATH)))
followers_popup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, FOLLOWERS_POPUP_XPATH)

for i in range(1, 6, 1):
    followers_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, FOLLOWERS_POPUP_XPATH)))
    followers_popup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, FOLLOWERS_POPUP_XPATH)
    driver.execute_script(script, followers_popup)
    time.sleep(5)

